# Running a C app in Netbeans with an argument

Tags: c, netbeans

I'm trying to pass an argument to a C app (code below) using the "Run Command" in Netbeans.  Shouldn't this work?

```
"${OUTPUT_PATH}" < input.txt
```

Where the input text is just "I like bacon".  If I do this in a terminal window (
"./in < input.txt" where "in" is what has been compiled ), it works as expected.

I want to be able debug the app I'm going to write but I need to be able to pass in a text file.  I thought I could use "Run Command" as I have when I used a file as an argument.  I want to pass in the text file as standard input, though, this time around.

Code...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    char c = getchar();

    while( c != EOF ) { 
        putchar(c);
        c = getchar();
    }

    return 0;

}
```

**UPDATE** - I switched to freopen and fgetc for now but would like to know if I can use redirect in Netbeans.  I have tried searching for a solution but so far the posts I've seen are rather old - hoping someone has a current work around if there is one. Otherwise, I'll work with freopen till I'm done with the app and then switch to standard input handling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got help from someone at Netbeans forum.  This works...

```
sh -c "${OUTPUT_PATH} < input.txt"
```

Posting it since other posts on Stack Overflow either mention not possible or some other method is given.

Comment: Though this does work, Netbeans crashes when trying to debug.  I ended up loading the file instead as a stream